# How to select all named class within a table row in jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-selectors

I am currently working on a bootstrap x-editable table. I need to select all nodes with a give named class **WITHIN** a table row and trigger their .editable(). Here is my jquery selector code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
   <thead>
      .............
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td><a class="myeditable editable-user" data-type="select" href="#">user...</a></td>
      <td><a class="myeditable editable-date" data-type="date" href="#">date...</a></td>
      <td><a class="myeditable editable-user" data-type="text" href="#">description..</a></td>
      <td><span class="actions"><a class="myButton" href="#">submit changes</a></span></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     .......... the same contents as above
   </tr>
</table>
```

my script should be something like:

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){
     // only this row of 'myeditable' should be selected
     $(this).closet('td')
          .siblings.children('.myeditable').editable('submit', {....}); 
});
```

Could anyone has a better solution to select elements by given classes within a table row under my Html structure?

Comment: closet should be closest and siblings in a method.. `$(this).closest('td').siblings().children('.myeditable')` it should work. Or just do `$(this).closest('tr').find('.myeditable')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You spelled `closest` wrongly. Change to `closest('tr')` and do a `find()` instead.

```
$('.myButton').click(function(){
     // only this row of 'myeditable' should be selected
     $(this).closest('tr')
          .find('.myeditable').editable('submit', {....}); 
});
```

Also, `editable()` is not a jQuery function. Are you using some plugin?